# How to set height depending on width percentage - pure css

Tags: html, css

I have a div that have a 50% of screen's width.
inside of it I want to make four ***squares***:

```
<div style="width:50%">
  <div style="width:25%"></div>
  <div style="width:25%"></div>
  <div style="width:25%"></div>
  <div style="width:25%"></div>
</div>
```

but I don't know how to calculate of height of them. I don't want to use `js`.

Comment: I don't understand what your desired end goal is. Could you maybe add an image or sketch describing it?

Comment: 4 squares depending on 25% of screen's width. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of percentages, have your inner `div`s use [viewport-percentage lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths):

```html
<div style="width:50%;background-color:red;">
    <div style="width:25vw;height:25vw;background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div style="width:25vw;height:25vw;background-color:green;"></div>
    <div style="width:25vw;height:25vw;background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div style="width:25vw;height:25vw;background-color:green;"></div>
</div>
```

(Background colors for the purpose of the demo.)